# Creating new record in a random access file issue

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to create a warehouse program for school using the random access file management.
I built a class called product(prodotto) with many private var and I must create a new record.

The function checks if the product already exists with the seekg pointer and reading the file. After u can write the file in that space if there is not. the key is the product code (codice).

The issue is that every time I run the function the former record is erased.

before this version I used a general `fstream` to do the work but it was worse. the file.dat was always empty.

I checked the pointers with tellg and tellp and they are ok. also the reading part seems ok. I think the problem is the writing statement.

This is the function:

```
void aggiungiProd()
{
    int code;
    string name,section, description;
    int quantity;
    double price;


    cout<<"\n(insert 0 to come back)"<<endl;

    //exit condiction

    cout<<"Insert product code:";

cin>>code;


if( cin.good()==0)
{ code=0;
    cout<<"invalid code. Please reinsert:"<<endl;
cin>>code;
} //also this part is not working but is less important


if(codice==0) return;//exit condition



ifstream readFile("prod.dat",ios::in);
if(!readFile){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading";
 exit(1);
    }
int var;
var=code-1;

//use a pointer to indicate the location to read
readFile.seekg(var * (sizeof(Prodotto)),ios::beg );


//reading the product record
Prodotto prodotto;
readFile.read(reinterpret_cast< char*> (&prodotto),sizeof(Prodotto));


readFile.close();
if(prodotto.getCod()==0)
{



//THIS PART IS ONLY ABOUT VARIABLES TO SET--> SKIP

cout<<"Inserisci il nome del prodotto (max 30 caratteri): ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,name);

if(name=="0") return;//condizione uscita

cout<<"Inserisci quantità da aggiungere: ";
cin>>quantita;

if(quantita==0) return;

cout<<"Inserisci il prezzo del prodotto: " ;
cin>>prezzo;

if(prezzo==0) return;

cout<<"Inserisci sezione di appartenenza del prodotto(max 15 caratteri): " ;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,sezione);

if(sezione=="0") return;

cout<<"Aggiungi una descrizione del prodotto (max 500 caratteri):";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,descrizione);

if(descrizione=="0") return;

//END OF THE VARIABLES INSERTION


//NOW PUT THE VARIABLES IN THE PRODUCT prodotto

    prodotto.setCod(codice);
    prodotto.setNome(nome);
    prodotto.setQta(quantita);
    prodotto.setPrz(prezzo);
    prodotto.setSez(sezione);
    prodotto.setDes(descrizione);

//open the file as output
ofstream inOutProd("prod.dat", ios::out );
if(!inOutProd){
        cerr<<"Error in the file creation";
 exit(1);
    }

//pointer for the location of the new record
inOutProd.seekp(var * (sizeof(Prodotto)));


//write the record prodotto
inOutProd.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&prodotto),sizeof(Prodotto));

//i believe the problem is in the statement over this line. I tried also to add ios::app
// in the ofstream line but it only append the new record at the end of file.



cout<<"the following product has been saved successfully\n"<<endl;
outputLine(cout,prodotto);
inOutProd.close();

}
else
{
    cerr<<"The product"<<codice<<"is already in our database"<<endl;

}

}
```

Comment: Yes and the result is that the program appends the data at the end of file but in that waythe pointer structure doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of the seekp call before writing a new record. If the file is not long enough to contain record N, seekp will return an error code and you must append data to the file such that it is long enough to contain record N.

Comment: seekp seems ok. the seekg resturns -1 (failure) with tellg. how could i catch this exception?
thank u for the answer :)

Comment: Check the status bits of the fstream after you call seekg. If the failbit is set, it indicates the requested postion in the file could not be reached -- the file is not long enough to contain the desired record.